# How to stop checking checkboxes after a number of checkboxes have been checked for a few questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I know how to stop checking checkboxes after a number of checkboxes have been checked. My problem is how to do this for a few questions, each of which can have multiple checkboxes ticked.

My code is at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drSJV/53/) and visible below:

**Code snippet**

```js
 
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(event) {
    if (this.checked && $('input:checked').length > 3) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('You\'re not allowed to choose more than 3 boxes');
    }
});
```

```html
<p><strong><em>Question 1 </em></strong></p>
 <br></br><br></br>
 <div id="Checklist1B10">
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td width="1%"> 
 <input type="checkbox"  name="QUESTION1" id="QUESTION1A1"/>
 </td> 
 <td width="15%">
 <label for="QUESTION1A1">Strongly Disagree4</label>
 </td>
 <td width="1%">
 <input type="checkbox" name="QUESTION1" id="QUESTION1A2"/>
 </td> 
 <td width="15%"> 
 <label for="QUESTION1A2">Disagree</label>
 </td> 
 <td width="1%"> 
 <input type="checkbox"  name="QUESTION1" id="QUESTION1A3"/> 
 </td> 
 <td width="15%"> 
 <label for="QUESTION1A3">Undecided</label>
 </td> 
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
 <td width="1%">
 <input type="checkbox"  name="QUESTION1" id="QUESTION1A4"/>
 </td> 
 <td width="15%">
 <label for="QUESTION1A4">Agree</label>
 </td> 
 <td width="1%">
 <input type="checkbox"  name="QUESTION1" id="QUESTION1A5"/>
 </td> 
 <td width="15%"><label for="QUESTION1A5">Strongly Agree </label>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
 <p><strong><em>Question 2 </em></strong></p>
<br></br> <br></br> 
<div class="c7" id="Checklist2B10"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="QUESTION2" id="QUESTION2A1"/>
<label for="QUESTION2A1">Monday</label>
<br></br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="QUESTION2" id="QUESTION2A2"/>
<label for="QUESTION2A2">Tuesday</label>
<br></br> 
<input type="checkbox"  name="QUESTION2" id="QUESTION2A3"/>
<label for="QUESTION2A3">Wednesday</label>
<br></br> 
<input type="checkbox"  name="QUESTION2" id="QUESTION2A4"/> 
<label for="QUESTION2A4">Thursday</label>
<br></br>
<input type="checkbox"  name="QUESTION2" id="QUESTION2A5"/> 
<label for="QUESTION2A5">Friday</label>
<br></br> 
<input type="checkbox"  name="QUESTION2" id="QUESTION2A6"/>
<label for="QUESTION2A6">Saturday</label>
<br></br> 
<input type="checkbox"  name="QUESTION2" id="QUESTION2A7"/> 
<label for="QUESTION2A7">Sunday</label>
<br></br> 
</div>
```

Comment: Add classes to the question sets i.e. Question 1 checkboxes have as `.question-1`, Question 2 as `.question-2`. Then you just run the function as: `$('.question-1').on('click', function(event) ...`

Comment: I would suggest taking all these checkboxes out of the table and wrapping these inside divs instead this way you can just point it as `$('.question-1 [type="checkbox"]')`, etc.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/naveencgr/drSJV/56/, i added a attribute of data-restricted to few checkbox, you can add for those which you want to restrict.

Comment: Maybe you should use some `css class` for separating each question and use that `class` to handle check checkboxes

Comment: how can i separate for each question ? please someone give me some example to explain :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small alteration in your if condition should do the trick.

Please let me know if you need any assistance

```
if (this.checked && $('input[name='+$(this).prop('name')+']:checked').length > 3) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('You\'re not allowed to choose more than 3 boxes');
}
```

Comment: I have edited this in your jsFiddle, and it is working!

You wanted the code to prevent user from checking more than three answers for each question right ?

Comment: It's working thanks a lot :)

Comment: Kindly check the below fiddle if this is what you are expecting :)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akhilarjun/drSJV/60/)

Answer (score 1):

Scope the check of how many are checked to some ancestor of each set of checkboxes:

```
 $(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(event) {
   var $this = $(this);
   if (this.checked && $this.closest('table,div').find('input:checked').length > 3) {
     event.preventDefault();
     alert('You\'re not allowed to choose more than 3 boxes');
   }
 });
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/drSJV/58/

In the example above I have to search for either a table or div as your page has inconsistent layouts.

This example also uses a delegated event handler as that is more efficient than dozens of individual event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use existing input names (*QUESTION1*, *QUESTION2*...) to limit selection:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(event) {
    if (this.checked && $('input[name=' + this.name + ']:checked').length > 3) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('You\'re not allowed to choose more than 3 boxes');
    }
});
```

Comment: it's working too thanks for your effort :)